# Solve the equation $18x^2-18x \sqrt{x}-17x-8 \sqrt{x}-2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, quadratics

> Solve the following equation. $$18x^2-18x \sqrt{x}-17x-8 \sqrt{x}-2=0.$$

Taking $\sqrt{x}=t$ we get equivalent equation $18t^4 -18t^3 - 17t^2-8t-2=0$.

From this point I have tried to factor it , write RHS as sum of two squares and its variants but nothing seem to work. Then putting the original equation in wolfram alpha I got solution $x=\frac{2}{9}(7+2 \sqrt{10})$. Can anyone suggest a method to solve it without wolfram alpha or any such computer method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking at Stack Exchange **is** a computer method ;-), and it's not always better than asking at Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: The quartic factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the condition is $x\geq 0$.

Now, as you did, put $t = \sqrt{x}$, then we have the equation.
$$18t^4-18t^3 -17t^2-8t-2 = 0.$$

Obviously, $t=0$ is not the solution of this equation. Then, we can divide two sides by $t^4$, $$18-\frac{18}{t}-\frac{17}{t^2}-\frac{8}{t^3}-\frac{2}{t^4} = 0$$
Let $u = \frac{1}{t}$, we have
$$18-18u-17u^2-8u^3-2u^4=0$$

$$25 - 5(u+1)^2 - 2(u+1)^4 = 0$$

Now, you can solve the quadratic equation of $(u+1)^2$:

$$(u+1)^2 = \frac{5}{2}$$
Thus, $u = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}-1 = \frac{\sqrt{10}-2}{2}$.

So, $t = \frac{1}{u} = \frac{\sqrt{10}+2}{3}$. Finally, $x = t^2 = \frac{14+4\sqrt{10}}{9}.$

Comment: Thanks. I have now understood the method of attack.

Comment: @GAVD How did you get $25-5(u+1)^2-2(u+1)^4=0$? Explain please. Thank you!

Comment: Well, this is one of the way of attack the 4-degrees equations. In fact, I go from the form $k(at^2+bt+c)^2 + l(at^2+bt+c) + m = 0$, but  it is really ugly, but nice for $\frac{1}{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{x}=\frac{t}{6}$.

Thus, we need to solve
$$18\cdot\frac{t^4}{1296}-18\cdot\frac{t^3}{216}-17\cdot\frac{t^2}{36}-8\cdot\frac{t}{6}-2=0$$ or
$$t^4-6t^3-34t^2-96t-144=0$$ or for all real $k$
$$(t^2-3t+k)^2-9t^2-k^2-2kt^2+6kt-34t^2-96t-144=0$$ or
$$(t^2-3t+k)^2-((2k+43)t^2-(6k-96)t+k^2+144)=0.$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $k$ such that
$$(2k+43)t^2-(6k-96)t+k^2+144=(at+b)^2,$$
for which we need
$$9(k-16)^2-(2k+43)(k^2+144)=0.$$
Easy to see that $k=-9$ is valid.

Id est, we need to solve
$$(t^2-3t-9)^2-(25t^2+150t+225)=0$$ or
$$(t^2-3t-9)^2-25(t+3)^2=0$$ or
$$(t^2-3t-9-5(t+3))(t^2-6t-9+5(t+3))=0$$ or
$$(t^2-8t-24)(t^2+2t+6)=0$$ or
$$t^2-8t-24=0$$ or
$$(t-4)^2=40,$$ which gives
$$6\sqrt{x}=4+\sqrt{40}$$ or
$$\sqrt{x}=\frac{2+\sqrt{10}}{3}$$ or
$$x=\frac{14+4\sqrt{10}}{9}.$$

Comment: @rugi My solution it's a solution by "pencil and paper",  without computer of course..

Comment: can you prove your Statement Michael?

Comment: About which statement do you say?

Comment: this here Michael: "My solution it's a solution by "pencil and paper", without computer of Course"

Comment: Sonnhard Just see my solution and try to restore it by yourself.

Comment: Same scam. "Easy to see that $k=-9$" How "easy" ? Please add to your answer that "I used Wolfram Alpha or computer software".  Even a 5 year old wouldn't believe you did it "by hand".

Comment: @User I did not use WA. I am ready to explain If you want. But I am not sure that you want to understand it.

Comment: Also. Why are you addressing me in such a tone?

Answer (score 0):

try the Ansatz $$18t^4-18t^3-17t^2-8t-2=(at^2+bt+c)(dt^2+et+f)$$